# Django configuring different databases

Tags: django, django-settings, django-database, django-mysql

I have 2 `database`s of interest, the basic one and the development one:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| projectsdb         |
| projectsdb_dev     |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In my django file `mysite/mysite/settings.py`, my databases are declared this way:

```
DATABASES = {  
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'projectsdb',
        'USER': 'projectsdb',
        'PASSWORD': 'notsecure',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

The allowed hosts is:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.xx.xxx.xx']  # I replaced it for the example
```

I start the server on the port 8006 which I use for developing:

```
$ python ./manage.py runserver xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8006
```

And here I modify the production database. I can switch to the dev database replacing the default database name:

```
DATABASES = {  
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'projectsdb_dev',
        'USER': 'projectsdb',
        'PASSWORD': 'notsecure',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

And it works fine, the server is interacting with the `projectsdb_dev` database. However I would like to keep both databases available in the settings file and I saw tutorials setting it up this way:

```
DATABASES = { 
    'default': {}, 
    'prod': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'projectsdb',
        'USER': 'projectsdb',
        'PASSWORD': 'notsecure',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    },  
    'dev': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'projectsdb_dev',
        'USER': 'projectsdb',
        'PASSWORD': 'notsecure',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }   
}
```

Now when I open the web page on xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8006, I get this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/

settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

I don't know if it's relevant but I also have this table:

```
mysql> select * from django_site;
+----+--------------------+----------------+
| id | domain             | name           |
+----+--------------------+----------------+
|  1 | example.com        | example.com    |
|  2 | xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8000 | projectsdb     |
|  3 | xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8006 | projectsdb_dev |
+----+--------------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I run the server specifying the correct database I want?

Answer (score 6):

I would say, create separate settings file for `dev` and `prod`. Or for the case of database only you can do with environment variables.

```
$ export ENV=PROD
```

Then in `settings.py`

```
import os
if os.environ.get('ENV') == "PROD":
    DATABASES = { 
      'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'projectsdb',
        'USER': 'projectsdb',
        'PASSWORD': 'notsecure',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
        }, 
    }
else:
    DATABASES = { 
      'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'projectsdb_dev',
        'USER': 'projectsdb',
        'PASSWORD': 'notsecure',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
        },
    }
```

Comment: How should the migrations for each database be managed? Can Django distinguish, between the created files in each `migrations` directory, the migrations that relate to each database?

Comment: Got the answer, it resides in the [MIGRATION_MODULES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIGRATION_MODULES) setting which can also change based on the `ENV` variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify a default database, you need to use automatic database routers in order to specify which database your models will use. You would write these router classes and then specify the DATABASE_ROUTERS setting to point to them. Routers basically contain some logic for telling database operations where to go, and you could include a check for whether or not this is a development environment.